# Mass of lamina defined in y ≥ 0, with edges given by y = 0, y = (4-x^2)/3 and x = −y + 2y^2, and density is y.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image][image]

I've been trying work this out, but I'm stuck on the the integral calculation. I've drawn a diagram, got all the points of intersection and relevant points, but I still can't get it. I had a go at defining my Type 1 and Type 2 domain, and I got this: D={(x,y)|0

Comment: Sorry I meant to write that my Domains were D={(x,y)|0<y<1, -y+2y^2<x<1} U {(x,y)| 1<x<2, 0<y<(4-x^2)/3}.

Comment: Have you tried sketching the domain D?

Comment: Done that, just cant seem to get the integration right, something about the way I've set up the order of integration is making it difficult.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the double integral you"ve set up?

Comment: Sure, Ill put it in a photo along with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integrals seem to be set up correctly. 
The first integral is
$$
\int_{y=0}^{1} \int_{x=2y^2-y}^{1} y dx dy \\
=\int_{y=0}^{1} y \; (1-(2y^2-y)) dy \\
=\int_{y=0}^{1} y-2y^3+y^2 \;dy \\
=1/2 - 1/2 + 1/3 \\
=1/3
$$

The second integral is
$$
\int_{x=1}^{2} \int_{y=0}^{4/3-x^2/3} y dy dx \\
=\frac{1}{2} \int_{x=1}^{2} \left( \frac{4-x^2}{3}\right)^2 dx \\
=\frac{1}{18} \int_{x=1}^{2}  x^4 - 8x^2 + 16 \; dx \\
=\frac{1}{18} \left[\frac{32-1}{5} -\frac{8}{3}(8-1) +16(2-1) \right] \\
=53/270
$$

So the mass is the sum of the two integrals, which is 143/270

Comment: Thank you! I had just forgotten to switch the order of integration according to Type 1 and Type 2 regions, I have confirmed and got the same answer as you now.